# Is this a correct way to test whether symbolic link has /proc/ directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I need to test whether `/etc/mtab`
is a symbolic link to `/proc/something`.
I need to comply with the POSIX standard.
(In general should run on RHEL 5 to RHEL 7.) 
This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(readlink -f /etc/mtab | grep '\/proc\/') ]; then
    echo do something related to proc
else
    echo do something other than proc
fi
```

Am I missing some edge cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What if `/etc/mtab` is a symbolic link to `/home/mikasa/proc/something`? 
   You should probably add a `^` to your grep regular expression.
2. Speaking of which, `/` is not a special character
   in regular expressions, so you don’t need to escape them.
3. You should quote shell variable references
   unless you have a good reason not to,
   and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. 
   This includes `$(…)` command substitutions. 
   In the truly pathological edge case where `/etc/mtab`
   is a symbolic link to `/proc/foo = bar`,
   your command expands to

   ```
   if [ /proc/foo = bar ]
   ```

   which,
   of course, evaluates to false. 
   You can fix this by putting the `$(…)` into double quotes:

   ```
   if [ "$(readlink -f /etc/mtab | grep '^/proc/')" ]; then
   ```
4. But you don’t need to do command substitution or `test` (a.k.a. `[`…`]`). 
   `grep` gives an exit status that indicates whether it found the pattern
   you told it to look for, so you should be able to simplify your command
   to:

   ```
   if readlink -f /etc/mtab | grep '^/proc/' > /dev/null; then
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to do what you want though `readlink -f` is not POSIX.

Another nice non-POSIX solution would be:

```
if [ "$(df --output=fstype  /etc/mtab  | tail -n +2)" = "proc" ]; then
```

(This should even work if the proc filesystem is not mounted on /proc)

But maybe in the real world it could be enough to simply check

```
if [ -L /etc/mtab ]; then
```

The last one is even used in util-linux test-suite and they got no bug reports so far. Seems like on any existing Linux distros /etc/mtab is either a regular file or a symlink to /proc/self/mounts.

Comment: Some of the experimental system do have a symbolic link to something which is not proc so could not rely on the last test.

Comment: OK then go with one of the GNUisms or see tlrobinson's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script